# How to open google Auth screen on a new browser tab

Tags: google-authentication

I am using google calendar API to add events to the calendar. But the Auth pop-up window is blocked by the browser for many times.  Is there anyway I can open it as a separate browser tab rather than a pop-up.
Because this kills the UX experience for the users. I am having many complains from users.